# facebook php connect check cookie

Tags: php, facebook

How to check if the user is logged of from facebook with php-sdk 3.1.1?
I'm doing like this:

```
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
```

So if user I know he is logged, but it take long time to communicate with facebook object, if I could only check with php if facebook coockie is there so I know if someone is logged in.

So it about optimalisation of speed, maybe it is also good idea to only once login with facebook and relay on my session or coockie

Can someone give me some feedback on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do the check, you can store the result somewhere, for example in a session.

You cannot check the cookie of another domain.

Comment: I can store it is no problem, but if someone logs off from facebook I again need to check if($user) and it needs to create facebook object and that takes time

Comment: You don't have much of a choice otheerwise. Facebook servers are fast (when they work, unlike today!) so the slowness is your end / your server. Move your server/site closer to Facebooks - plonk your website on a server in California.

Answer (score 0):

The [getUser()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) method will try to get the user id from signed request (either from request or cookie). It won't call Facebook servers by default.

You don't loose any performance/speed in creating Facebook object.

**You should follow this pseudo code:**

```
call getUser method
if user 
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    get user data using graph api
    store it in session
  else
    if($_SESSION['user']['fb_id'] != $user){
    get user data using graph api
        store it in session         
    end
  end

end
```